# MutationObserver for HTML template

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Seems like `MutationObserver` is not working on a `<template>` tag.
https://jsfiddle.net/brhya5uj/

What's the best way to get notified when a `<template>` changes?

Comment: You need to observe `.content` property of the template.

Comment: Oh - that easy :-) Please post it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the specification `template` element doesn't have any children. Instead, the **contents is placed inside `content` property**, which you should observe:

```js
new MutationObserver(console.log)
  .observe(document.querySelector('template').content, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template